# Angular 14 - Send a parameter that is an object to the router-outlet directive

Tags: angular, router-outlet

I have the following component template: users.component.html:

```
<app-user-card class="card-container" *ngIf="user" [user]="user"></app-user-card>
<div>
  <router-outlet *ngIf="user"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

User is an object like this:

```
this.user = {
  id: 1,
  name: "Jonh",
  icon: "jonhn.svg",
  subsusers: [],
}
```

I need to pass the "User" object to the "router-outlet" and receive it on all components used in that routes.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For v16 the solution would probably be to rely on input bindings combined with the resolver :

```
provideRouter(
      [
        {
          path: 'todos/:todoId',
          data: {
            isSomething: true, 
          },
          resolve: { resolveFoo: () => 'My resolved data' },
          component: TodoComponent,
        },
      ],
      withComponentInputBinding() // to enable input bindings
    ),
```

The component with the binded inputs:

```
@Component({
  ...
  standalone: true,
})
export default class TodoComponent {
  @Input() resolveFoo: string; // My resolved data
  @Input() isSomething: boolean; // true
  @Input() todoId: string; // 1
}
```

Since you are "stucked" on v14, you should probably share the data through a provided service between the components.

Comment: I will try to migrate it to 16, for the moment as you say I will do it with a service, thanks.